# Вывод записей из БД как во ВКонтакте

Tags: php, mysql

Необходимо выбрать все строки таблицы `MySQL`, начиная с последней (максимальный `id`) и выводить по 15 записей, и еще необходимо создать кнопку, при нажатии на которую `MySQL` будет выводить еще 15 записей. Это как во ВКонтакте.

```
<?php

function printResult ($result_set) {
    while (($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc()) != false)
    {
        echo $row["story"];
        echo "</br>";
    }
}


$mysqli->query ("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$result_set = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM  `story` ");

printResult ($result_set);
$mysqli->close()
?>
```

Comment: Ну это чистым php нельзя сделать, нужен javascript и ajax

Comment: Не [бесконечная прокрутка](https://www.alexeykopytko.com/2015/universal-infinite-scrolling/) ли это?